# mitmproxyの証明書をiPhoneにインストールできない

Tags: network, iphone, proxy

前提:
Pythonを使用してpipでmitmproxyをインストール済です。Pythonのバージョンは3.11でwindows10を使用。
使用しているiphoneのバージョンは16.5.1です。

まずコマンドプロンプトでmitmproxyを起動します。その後ipアドレスと8080のポートでパソコンのwifiの設定からプロキシを手動にして入力します。それからパソコンのファイアウォールの設定を無効にしてからmitm.itに接続し、iosのmitmproxy-ca-cert.pemをダウンロードします。その後ファイアウォールを有効にしてからメールで自分が使用しているiphoneに送ります。届いたメールを開くと証明書（X.509)が表示されるのできちんとできているはずです。しかしファイルを開こうとするとインストールのボタンがでてこないです。
証明書をきちんとiphoneでインストールできるようにしたいのですが、どうしたらいいでしょうか？

*パソコンのwifiの設定でプロキシを手動にする理由はiphoneで同様の操作をすると回線の接続が切れることからまずパソコンで手動にします。iphoneでプロキシを手動からオフに切り替えると通常通りwifiが使えるようになります。この原因も知りたいです。
*フィアウォールを無効にする理由は無効にしないとmitm.itに接続できないからです。有効のままだと接続できませんでした。
*グーグルのプライバシーとセキュリティのデバイス証明管理からmitmproxyを見ると信頼されない発行元にあります。このサイトを参考にしてもきちんと認識されませんでした。

https://picscels.site/mitmproxy-certificate-trap/

Comment: 「パソコンのwifiの設定でプロキシを手動にする理由はiphoneで同様の操作をすると回線の接続が切れる」とのことですが、まず証明書の問題よりこちらを解決した方が良いと思います。
プロキシ経由での接続が出来ていなければ、インストールした証明書が機能しているのかも分かりません。

Comment: iPhone には詳しく無いですが、一般に証明書をインストールしていなくとも、プロキシの設定を行ない、 http://mitm.it/ へ接続して証明書のダウンロードページを表示させることはできるはずです。
これが出来ないということは何か設定を間違えているのでしょう。
どういった設定を行なったのか、その設定に使用した値（IPアドレスなど）をどうやって確認したのか、などの情報を含めて質問すると回答が得られ易いと思います。

Comment: そもそも iPhone からパソコンに通信が通っているのかも確定した方が良いでしょう。
例えば、`mitmweb` を起動するとデフォルトでポート 8081 つまり、パソコン自身からだと http://127.0.0.1:8081/ のWebインターフェースが開かれると思います。
この画面に iPhone からパソコンのIPアドレスを用いてアクセスできているでしょうか。

Comment: @mjy 
IPアドレスの確認方法はコマンドでipconfigと打つことで出てくるWireless LAN adapter Wi-FiのIPv4 アドレスから確認しました。これをiphoneでwifiのプロキシを手動にして打ってからmitmproxyで確認すると以下のようなエラーが出ていました
client and mitmproxy cannot agree on a tls version to use
the client does not trust the proxy's certificate

Comment: iPhone で `http://mitm.it` ヘアクセスすると、mitmproxy 側にその「client and mitmproxy cannot agree...」というエラーが表示される、ということですか？
（`http` であれば証明書関連のエラーは出ないのではとも思うのですが）

Comment: @mjy
先ほどはパソコンで開いたため解答のエラーが出ていました。プロキシを手動に変更してiphoneのグーグルでmitm.itと入力すると接続できました。mitmproxyを確認するとhttp get mitm.itが表示されています

Comment: つまり現在、iPhoneでmitmproxy経由でWebに接続できている、という事ですね。
そして、Googleに接続しても証明書のエラーが出ていないという事で間違いないですか？
そうだとすると、証明書のインストールも終っているようです。
何も問題が無さそうです。何か問題が残っていますか？

Comment: @mjy
iphoneのサファリからインストールする必要があることを失念していました。
パソコンの方でmitm.itを開いていろいろな操作をする必要があると勘違いしていたことが原因だと思います。無事にできました。
初歩的なミスですみませんでした。

Comment: よかったですね。
成功した手順を簡単にまとめて回答になさると良いと思います。
[自己回答は推奨されています](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)。